# Recommended way from dart team to catch errors when using await in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I write a lot of async code that uses `await` to handle `Futures`.

If I have

```
() async {
  var result = await someFuture();
}
```

what would be the preferred way to catch errors. Wraping the code in try/catch or doing

```
() async {
  var result = await someFuture().catch(_errorHandler);
}
```

EDIT:

Also, if I have many await calls in one async method, what is the preferred catch all the errors instead of writing `.catchError` for eachOne.

```
() async {
  var result = await someFuture();
  var result2 = await someFuture2();
  var result3 = await someFuture3();

}
```

Comment: I suppose that when using `try` and `catch` your code would not continue executing, but continuing in the `catch` block after an exception is thrown. However, it will continue if you catch it like you proposed.

Comment: I edited the question for another case.

Comment: Questions that can be qualified as "Primarily opinion based" don't fit stackoverflow. As they don't have a finite answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the Dart docs if you use await wrap it in a try-catch

Comment: Hi Thomas, I think your right, but when I look at the documentation: https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling I don't see any example of that.
Can you maybe share an example you use or to the the documentation? Just curious :)

Comment: So, a `Future.error(...)` within the async function will be catched by the outer `try`/`catch`?

Comment: nope, they won't

Comment: Huh? What is the point then?

Comment: you have to await the call inside a try-catch. if you have a Future.error that will  receive the exception and not the try catch around it

Answer (score 3):

According to the Dart docs if you use await wrap it in a try-catch

https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#handling-errors

Answer (score 3):

The Docs suggest just wrapping in a `try-catch`

Example code:

```dart
try {
  print('Awaiting user order...');
  var order = await fetchUserOrder();
} catch (err) {
  print('Caught error: $err');
}
```

Reference also has a runnable example https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#handling-errors